# What does this verse of SB say about Multiverse?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, universe

Lord Śiva said:

> My dear son, I, Lord Brahmā and the other devas, who move within this universe under the misconception of our greatness, cannot exhibit any power to compete with the Supreme Personality of Godhead, for innumerable universes and their inhabitants come into existence and are annihilated by the simple direction of the Lord **(Bhagavata Purana 9.4.56)**

- Please explain the meaning of this verse.
- Are other universe's inhabitants and their life cycle different from our universe according to scriptures?

Comment: Multiverse is not mentioned in Vedas. Puranas certainly mention it which I also discuss in my [answer here.](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/what-are-some-scientific-facts-described-in-hindu-scriptures/17445#17445)

Comment: Do you literally mean the word "Vedas" or you meant Hindu scripture in general?

Comment: I mean hindu scriptures.