# Does the concept of multiverse exist in vedas?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas

Does the concept of multiverse exist in vedas just like puranas in samhitas,aranyakas,brahmanas and major upnishads.

I think it's a puranic concept if i am right then give evidences that establish **one world theory**.

Comment: Related posts :  [What does this verse of SB say about Multiverse?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/what-does-this-verse-of-sb-say-about-multiverse) , [Are there other Brahmas and universes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/593/are-there-other-brahmas-and-universes) and [Which Hindu scriptures talk about multiple universes or planets?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/which-hindu-scriptures-talk-about-multiple-universes-or-planets)

Comment: @Ankit sharma i know they are in purans but do vedas correspond to this theory if not' then do vedas says of **one world concept** (that there is only one world).

Comment: The multiverse is a misnomer. If what they say is correct then the universe is simply a lot larger than we have previously understood. So far, the evidence is circumstantial.