# Which Hindu scripture is saying that sun does not rise or set?

Tags: scripture, vedas, surya

The boldified text of the [following](https://journeynorth.org/tm/mclass/SunriseSetAns.html) sentence is a well known fact about sun now

> The sun stays in its position at the center of our solar system. **It
>   doesn't rise and set. But it appears to rise and set** because of the
>   Earth's rotation on its axis. It makes one complete turn every 24
>   hours. It turns toward the east.

Which scripture explicitly tells the same?

Comment: Aitareya Brahmana is one of such scriptures..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are some scientific facts described in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17442/what-are-some-scientific-facts-described-in-hindu-scriptures)

Comment: @YDS But that is also a closed question!

Comment: Since you now know the answer, you can write your own answer and accept it. Doesn't look like a dup. to me. This is a very specific question about one scientific aspect. As a general rule, we shouldn't close a specific question as a dup of a generic question.