# The story of Ramayana found in Ramacharitamanas belongs to which kalpa?

Tags: ramayana, rama, kalpa, ramcharitmanas

I have seen somewhere (not able to recall the source now) that Ramacharitamanas belongs to a kalpa named 'Pitri' Kalpa.
Is it true?
If not , then the story of ramacharitamanas is of which kalpa?

Comment: I think you might have read it [from here](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-Tulsidas-wrote-a-different-story-than-Valmiki-Ramayan/answer/Phani-Kasyap?ch=15&oid=230257093&share=65f38bc8&srid=hpFczE&target_type=answer). But, we all know, Quora ain't a good source! :D

Comment: @Vivikta Yes Most probably....Actually I read it long ago and suddenly the question popped..So asked here...BTW Is there a kalpa named pitri kalpa and can u help me out with the question?

Comment: Of course, Pitri is the previous Kapla in which Devi Sati was born and immolated herself through Yoga-Agni. I'll try to answer your question, if possible through "acceptable-sources".

Comment: @Vivikta Salute to ur memory :O ..U r able to remember so many minor details from scriptures...But I tend to forget them ^_^;   BTW thank you for your help :D

Comment: @Vivikta I think the concept of 'pitri kalpa' must have arised becoz of RCM where the story of Devi Sati is present. It's implicitly mentioned like...Lord Rama went to forest...Devi Sati testing him...Coming to lord Shiva...Lord Shiva abandoning her....Daksha's Sacrifice and then Immolation. I think that's how people do it...connect both the instances. Wot r ur thoughts on this?

Comment: It's kind of narration between narrative between Shiva and Uma, and also Garuda and Kakabhusunda. We know, bhusunda is [immune to kalpanta pralaya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50785/17833). So, turns out it might be an intermix, but mostly it might be loyal to Valmiki, also [Read this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7767/what-are-the-main-differences-between-valmiki-ramayana-and-ram-charit-manas)

Comment: When I had read the RCM, I also thought that to be an intermix and I still think so. But I think this is the reason why the concept of 'RCM includes the story of Pitri Kalpa' must have arisen. People must have linked the two stories and posted on different sites. This is my analysis of this statement. @Vivikta

Comment: I concur with you on this. :)

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/49336/26679  @Vivikta what do you think of this answer? Specially the 'note' part, I heard this thing  first time that RCM belongs to this kalpa and is of Svayambhuva Manvantara.

Comment: I can't say with surety, the Op has given references, but it's all contradicting. Scriptures have all sorts of contradiction. As per Skanda Purana Verse 7.1.7.25-40,  Sati was born is the previous Kalpa, Pitr. So as. Per precedence I'll give more preference to Puranas. See my this question - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51297/17833